# Incremental game formula issue

Tags: c#, math

I've recently been contracted to develop the incremental mechanics of a mobile game, which is a first for me. So, I've been following the advice and guidance found in a [blog post from Kongregate in 2016](https://blog.kongregate.com/the-math-of-idle-games-part-i/) and the formulas listed at the bottom to use instead of potentially lengthy for-loops work great, except for the max formulas, both of which results in the game trying to buy way more than the player has currency for.
For the sake of ease to read, I broke down down the standard log formula into parts, so my method looks like this:

```cs
//genCoeff is the coefficient that sets the rate of cost increase.
//For experiment purposes, totalMoney is 1000, genCoeff is 1.1, baseCost is 5, and currentGenLevel is 1
double Numerator = moneyManager.totalMoney * (genCoeff - 1);
double Denominator = baseCost * (Math.Pow(genCoeff, currentGenLevel));
maxLevels = (int)Math.Floor((Math.Log(Numerator / Denominator) + 1) / Math.Log(genCoeff));
```

I'm hoping someone can point out to me where my mistake is

Edit: On a whim, I changed the final step of the formula to be this

```
maxLevels = (int)Math.Floor((Math.Log(Numerator / Denominator)) / Math.Log(genCoeff));
```

And now it seems to work perfectly, but I'd still like to know where the issue was.

Edit 2: I let it run for a while, and max buy seems to fall behind what the player has money for.

Edit 3: See my comment below. I can't mark the question as answered yet...

Answer (score 1):

Switching to the non-standard log base seems to work properly, even after letting it run for a while.

```cs
maxLevels = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log((Numerator / Denominator) + 1, genCoeff));
```